# Logstash output-http plugin error 500 when trying to send to slack webhook

Tags: logstash

I'm running a docker container with an ELK stack. Everythings working dandy and fine. I'd like to utilize the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html plugin.

I install the plugin it:

```
root@elk:/# /opt/logstash/bin/plugin install logstash-output-http
Validating logstash-output-http
Installing logstash-output-http
Installation successful
```

`/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf` main logstash config file:

```
input {
  beats {
   port => 5044
   type => "logs"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\"name\":\"Error\""}
    add_tag => ["error"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
  if "error" in [tags] {
    http {
      http_method => "post"
      url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<MY_ID>"
      format => "json"
      content_type => "application/json"
      message => "{\"text\": \"dis is workinz\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried changing the format in the http:

```
...
format => "message"
...
```

The configuration is also tested and is valid:

```
root@elk:/# /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf 
Configuration OK
```

Both result in it not working. I double checked to make sure the webhook is working with a test (from the logstash docker container):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"text":"testing"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/<MY_ID>
```

I know tags are being applied properly, checked in Kibana. Also the if clause is also working as I tested putting `elasticsearch` inside it and it indeed only sent logs with the added `error` tags to elasticsearch.

Lastly the holy error message from `/var/log/logstash/logstah.log`:

```
{: timestamp => "2016-02-25T15:55:35.926000+0000", 
: message => "[HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-200 HTTP code 200", 
: response_code => 500, : url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<YES_THE_ACTUAL_WEBHOOK_ID_WAS_HERE>", 
: event => # < LogStash::Event: 0x408e202@ metadata = {
        "beat" => "filebeat", "type" => "log"
    }, @accessors = # < LogStash::Util::Accessors: 0x5dc514d7@ store = {
        "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
            "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
        }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
    }, @lut = {
        "@timestamp" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "@timestamp"], "beat" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "beat"], "count" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "count"], "fields" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "fields"], "input_type" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "input_type"], "offset" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "offset"], "source" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "source"], "type" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "type"], "[beat][hostname]" => [{
            "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
        }, "hostname"], "host" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "host"], "tags" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "tags"], "message" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "message"], "[tags]" => [{
            "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
                "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
            }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
        }, "tags"]
    } > , @data = {
        "message" => "{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-25T15:55:25.509Z\",\"v\":0}", "@version" => "1", "@timestamp" => "2016-02-25T15:55:34.004Z", "beat" => {
            "hostname" => "sensu-node-dev", "name" => "sensu-node-dev"
        }, "count" => 1, "fields" => nil, "input_type" => "log", "offset" => 29352, "source" => "/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log", "type" => "log", "host" => "sensu-node-dev", "tags" => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "error"]
    }, @metadata_accessors = # < LogStash::Util::Accessors: 0x22cd112d@ store = {
        "beat" => "filebeat", "type" => "log"
    }, @lut = {
        "[type]" => [{
            "beat" => "filebeat", "type" => "log"
        }, "type"], "[beat]" => [{
            "beat" => "filebeat", "type" => "log"
        }, "beat"]
    } > , @cancelled = false > , : level => : error
}
```

As you can see it states `response_code => 500` internal error. I get the same error with both `format => "json"` and `format => "message"`.

I'm guessing it has something to do with my configuration (obviously).

Comment: why not using logstash slack plug in?
here is the git hub url: https://github.com/cyli/logstash-output-slack

Comment: @zhoubo It's a simple http post request, feels overkill to use a plugin just for slack when the http plugin does exactly the same thing basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently logstash has issues with double quotes, I am surprised (and disappointed). Here is working code:

```
  if "error" in [tags] {
    http {
      http_method => "post"
      url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<MY_ID>"
      format => "message"
      message => '{"text":"hello"}'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'm surprised this is just about the only hit on Google that showed how to do this.

Comment: @Elvar Indeed. My questions (her efor example) are so bad apparantly that I can no longer ask questions on server fault hah.